# Replace string in text using regular expression

Tags: java

I need to replace all strings in text that are:

`someString+"["` or `someString+"{"` or `someString+"("`.

I haven't nothing try yet, but i think `String.replaceAll()` + regular expressions will help me, but i don't know how to use them in this case.

Comment: Think, code, post. You won't get any help without posting your attempts.

Comment: Isn't replace() method enough?

Comment: Replace them with what? Show us an example input and expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that someString may contain pretty much anything and is a given literal that you need to find and replace everywhere in text:

```
text.replaceAll(Pattern.quote(someString) + "[\\[\\{\\(]", replaceWithThisLiteralString);
```

Notice the escaping on parentheses inside the character class.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
String someString;
String newString = someString.replace('sth', 'sthelse');
```